# Check if a string is a complete match for a regex expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if a string completely matches a regex in python 3.

For example, if I had :

```
regex = "(A*B)*"
stringone = "AABAABB"
stringtwo = "ABCAAB"
```

- stringone would be a match for regex,
- stringtwo would not be a match.

I tried using the built-in re module but I kept getting none type objects no matter what I did.

This is my code

```
compiled_regex = re.compile(regex)
if compiled_regex.match(string).group(0) == string:
    print("Match")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add start of line (`^`) and end of line (`$`) patterns to your regex pattern:

```
regex = r"^(A*B)*$"

pattern = re.compile(regex)
for s in "AABAABB", "ABCAAB", "B", "BBB", "AABAABBx", "xAABAABB":
    if pattern.match(s):
        print "Matched:", s
```

This outputs:

```
Matched: AABAABB
Matched: B
Matched: BBB
```

Or you can use your regex with the match object too, but use `group()`, not `groups()`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(A*B)*')
for s in "AABAABB", "ABCAAB", "B", "BBB", "AABAABBx", "xAABAABB":
    m = pattern.match(s)
    if m is not None and m.group() == s:
        print "Matched:", s
```

Outputs:

```
Matched: AABAABB
Matched: B
Matched: BBB
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression works fine, look:

```
import re

regex = "(A*B)*"
stringone = "AABAABB"
stringtwo = "ABCAAB"

compiled_regex = re.compile(regex)
if compiled_regex.match(stringone):
    print("Match")
    print(compiled_regex.match(stringone))
```

Outputs:

```
Match                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='AABAABB'>
```

If you want to additionally check that the string does not contain anything besides what the regex specifies you should use the `^` and `$`, as so:

```
regex = "^(A*B)*$"
```

Comment: But if I replace stringone with stringtwo it would still print Match which I don't want it to do, I want a complete match.

Comment: @JeLLyB0x3r Yes, it would, because it IS a match. To get a complete match you should use the start and end markers, see my edit